# using backbone.js to write save function with extra params

Tags: backbone.js, model

I am in a new Backbone.js . I need to send some variables with save function in my app. For example:
 `myModel.save({variabl1,variabl2,..}, {
     success: function() {}
});`

Variable is not related myModel. But I don't know how to do it. If You know how to do it, please, tell me!

Comment: I already did it, but it was not helpful, in server side kep geting null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass parameters in the options has of save method.

```
myModel.save(
    {variabl1,variabl2,..}, 
    { success: function() {}, 
      data: {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }  
});
```

Comment: Can You aks me how to get params in server side. I am using java, it will be that: @RequestParam(value="value1", required = false) String  value1

Comment: you wrong. data attribute in options override the setted values

Answer (score 0):

I found the way :

```
myModel.save( null, { 
      headers: {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2' }, 
      success: function() {} 

});
```

Maybe anyone will useful the code.